# Keyboard shortcuts for docking windows

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, window, shortcuts

Windows has a feature that allows you to press Win+RightArrow and have the active window dock to the right side of the screen.  In Ubuntu I can click and drag the window to the right edge of the screen and it will do the same thing, but is there a way to set up keyboard shortcuts for this?

I am using Kubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

If you open up "Global keyboard settings", there is a section there for "Kwin" - the kde window manager.

Find the setting for "Quick tile window to the right" or "left", and assign it a shortcut key by selecting it and pressing the button that says "None". For example, "Win-Alt-Left" for quick-tiling to the left. Press "Apply" and you can now use this shortcut.

[image: Global shortcuts in 5.9]